# A taxonomy of Meta-Ethics (Reference Request)

Tags: reference-request, metaethics

On the accounts of many Doctors of Philosophy specialising in Meta-Ethics, the philosophical landscape is notoriously hard to taxonomise. What are the best comprehensive guides to Meta-Ethics. I have in mind things such as collections of key essay, " X's introduction-to" and authors potential work on the general area (rather than a specific aspect of it).

Any recommendations will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that the general overview can be taxonomized relatively well. There's even reasonable flowcharts, like you'll find in Alex Miller's *Contemporary Metaethics* [(see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osxo2.jpg). For general introduction, a short standard paper would be [Finlay's overview](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~finlay/Moral%20Realism.pdf). For constructivism, Street has [an overview](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1747-9991.2009.00280.x). Miller's and Fisher's introductory books are supposed to be good.

(By the way: r/ethics has changed mods. They made a huge FAQ with reading lists. Part of it is metaethics. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ethics/wiki/faq#wiki_1.4_further_introductory_reading))

I believe the main issue comes with theories on reasons or on motivation. Detailed accounts which try to maneuvre around problems resist getting put neatly into categories.